# Spring : How to remove bean reference using listMergeDirective in list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I have one list defined in spring.xml file.

```
<util:list id="addToCartMethodHooks"
                  value-type="com.test.AddToCartMethodHook"/>
```

Where `AddToCartMethodHook` is an Interface and the idea is to give flexibility to create any number of classes which implement this interface and hook that bean into list.

We can use `listMergeDirective` to add new bean definition where ever required.

```
<bean id="customAddToCartMethodHook" class="com.test.CustomAddToCartMethodHook" />

<bean id="customAddToCartMethodHookMergeDirective" depends-on="addToCartMethodHooks" parent="listMergeDirective">
        <property name="add" ref="customAddToCartMethodHook"/>
</bean>
```

Lets say i want to override list reference by removing some of existing bean reference. **Is there any way we can remove bean reference using listMergeDirective ?**

I also checked `ListMergeDirective` class in spring, there is no remove functionality available.

One way is to override existing class with removing all code with `#do nothing()` and using alias to remove. But this ultimately creating overhead to create new classes.

How can we just remove the reference using only beans ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this feature was introduced in 1811 version. the new `ListMergeDirective` was enhanced with a `remove` property. Since then the usual workaround i did was to override the bean(only) and provide a new set of post-processor-hooks from zero.